# Problem copying example Hands-on start p264

Tags: plotting

I am trying to replicate an example given in Hands-on start to mathematica. It starts at the bottom of p263. The following code is taken verbatim:

```
soln = DSolveValue[{y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0}, y[x], x]
solnTable  =  Table[soln /. {C[1] \[RightArrow] i, C[2] \[RightArrow] j}, {i, -1,    1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}]
```

But running this gives:

```
E^(-x/2) C[2] Cos[(Sqrt[3] x)/2] + E^(-x/2) C[1] Sin[(Sqrt[3] x)/2]
```

[Which is expected]

However  then I get:

```
ReplaceAll:{C[1]\[RightArrow]-1,C[2]\[RightArrow]-1}  is neither a \
list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot \
be used for replacing"
```

This line is repeated for the other values of i and j.

What I don't get is this is an exact copy from the book. I'm using V12 of the student edition. Any thoughts?

Kevin

Comment: Somehow it copied over as `\[RightArrow]` but it should be `\[Rule]` or simply enter a dash followed by a greater than symbol `->`. These arrows indicate rules in Mathematica. In this case, it causes `C[1]` to be replaced with `i` and `C[2]` to be replaces with `j`.

Comment: That's great - many thanks.